# Chrome 76 Copy Content to Clipboard using navigator

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, clipboard, navigator

I just updated to chrome 76 stable and am trying to use the new clipboard API to copy some text (and later on, images) to the clipboard. However, `navigator.clipboard.write(data)` does not seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Wriing to clipbard");  
    navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'clipboard-write' }).then(result => {
        if (result.state === 'granted') {
            var data = new Blob(["Text data"], {type : "text/plain"});
            navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(function() {
              console.log("Copied to clipboard successfully!");
            }, function(error) {
              console.error("unable to write to clipboard. Error:");
              console.log(error);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("clipboard-permissoin not granted: " + result);
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

I am running this in a chrome extension content script, with clipboard permissions set, so the permissions indeed get granted. The eror that gets thrown is:

`unable to write to clipboard. Error:`

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'write' on 'Clipboard': Iterator getter is not callable.
```

Strangely enough, when I use `navigator.clipboard.write text(text)` instead of `navigator.clipboard.write(data)`, everything works perfectly. The thing is, I want to use `write(data)` because later on I want to write images to the clipboard as well. Any ideas why it's not working? Thank you.

EDIT: I got the code from the specsheet https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#dom-clipboard-write

UPDATE: Okay, I got the text-copying to work by using ClipboardItem (see my answer below) but if I do the same with a dataURL encoded image, the whole webpage crashes with an "Aw snap" message. So not sure what's going on there. Here is the code that will crash the site and force a reload:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Wriing to clipbard");  
    navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'clipboard-write' }).then(result => {
        if (result.state === 'granted') {
            //var blob = new Blob(['hello'], {type: 'text/plain'});
            var data = new Blob(["iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+P+/HgAFhAJ/wlseKgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="], {type : "image/png"});

            var item = new ClipboardItem({'image/png': data});
            navigator.clipboard.write([item]).then(function() {
              console.log("Copied to clipboard successfully!");
            }, function(error) {
              console.error("unable to write to clipboard. Error:");
              console.log(error);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("clipboard-permissoin not granted: " + result);
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this is the solution that works for me. You had to wrap the blob in a ClipboardItem object before calling write(). I stumbled across the solution by reading https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150835 and then searching for "ClipboardItem" on the web and then finding this code https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/master/clipboard-apis/async-navigator-clipboard-basics.https.html. There doesn't seem to be a real documentation for this yet, but hey, it works!

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Wriing to clipbard");  
    navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'clipboard-write' }).then(result => {
        if (result.state === 'granted') {
            var blob = new Blob(['hello'], {type: 'text/plain'});
            var item = new ClipboardItem({'text/plain': blob});
            navigator.clipboard.write([item]).then(function() {
              console.log("Copied to clipboard successfully!");
            }, function(error) {
              console.error("unable to write to clipboard. Error:");
              console.log(error);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("clipboard-permission not granted: " + result);
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

UPDATE: Okay, I also got the image copying to work (looking at the same source). url is the url of the image (duh)

```
async function copyImage(url) {
    console.log("Wriing to clipbard");  

    const response = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    const item = new ClipboardItem({'image/png': blob});
    await navigator.clipboard.write([item]).then(function() {
      console.log("Copied to clipboard successfully!");
    }, function(error) {
      console.error("unable to write to clipboard. Error:");
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more complete solution:

After having several problems trying to solve this issue, I have a solution that works with Safari, but also with all the others browsers.

We need to try the two scenarios (for Safari and for the rest):

```
getImage (canvas, width = 200, height = 200) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    tmpCanvas.width = width
    tmpCanvas.height = height
    const ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d')
    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, width, height)
    tmpCanvas.toBlob(resolve)
  })
}

copyImg () {
 const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]
 if (canvas instanceof HTMLCanvasElement) {
   try {
     // Trying for only Safari browser
     const image = getImage(canvas)
     navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ 'image/png': image })])
     console.log('Copied')
   } catch (safariError: any) {
     try {
       // Trying for rest of browsers
       canvas.toBlob(blob => navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ 'image/png': blob })]))
       console.log('Copied')
     } catch (anotherBrowserError: any) {
       console.log(safariError.message + ' - ' + anotherBrowserError.message)
     }
   }
 }
```

}